# Jmeter Duration exceeded though is fixed

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I tried to run Thread group with below details:

- Number of thread: 50
- Ramp-up period: 120
- Duration : 300 s
- Loop count: 1 (I create a Loop Controller under Thread Group -infinite loop count box unchecked)
- HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m

and I set a Constant Timer for (5000ms) as think time after the request
The Problem I have ,is the test has exceeded the duration time....and I don't know when it will finish (the command did not show the prompt)
this is the Jmeter log:

```
09:15:40,486 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread: Thread Group 1-46
09:15:40,486 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-46
```

what did I wrong on this scenario?

is there any idea how to fix it....(Link for screenshot):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyoSk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. Your [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) does nothing, it controls how many times its **children** will be executed and since it doesn't have any children it doesn't make any sense.
2. Your 2 log lines are not very informative, if you want to know for sure where JMeter is stuck you need to take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and see what exactly the threads are doing. A "blind shot": at least one of your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers fails to get response in 5 minutes as the application doesn't respond or there is another transport-layer problem. Consider setting reasonable connect and response timeouts at the "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or even better use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/))

   [image]
3. Your heap size might be too low, consider [monitoring heap space usage and garbage collector activity](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html) using i.e. [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)
4. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)